# Place numbers from a list to an array where the element is not a np.nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numbers

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and an existed array

```
b = [[np.nan, 10, np.nan], 
     [11,     12,     13], 
     [np.nan, 14, np.nan]]
```

How can I place the numbers from *"list `a`"* to the elements on array `b` that contains a number which I should get

```
c = [[np.nan, 1, np.nan], 
     [2,      3,      4], 
     [np.nan, 5, np.nan]]
```

Maybe it can be done with loops but I want to avoid it because the length of the list and the dimension of the array will change. However, the length of the list will always match the number of the elements that are not an `np.nan` in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to solve it without using loops.

First, we flatten the array b to convert it to a 1D array and then replace the none nan values with contents of a. Then, convert the array back to its initial shape.

```
flat_b = b.flatten()
flat_b[~np.isnan(flat_b)] = a
flat_b.reshape(b.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to create a boolean mask. Then use it in indexing<sup>1</sup>.

```
m     = np.isnan(b)
b[~m] = a
print(b)
[[nan  1. nan]
 [ 2.  3.  4.]
 [nan  5. nan]]
```

---

<sub>1. [NumPy's Boolean Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
c = b
current = 0
for i in range(len(c)):
    for j in range(len(c[i])):
        if c[i][j] != np.nan and current < len(a):
            c[i][j] = a[current]
            current += 1
```

While this may look long and complicated, it actually only has a O(n) complexity. It just iterates through the 2D array and replaces the non-nan values with the current value from `a`.

Comment: This approach is not O(n). If you consider n = len(a) and m = len(c) and k = len(c[0]), then it is O(n.m.k).

Comment: Also the "if" condition should be `!=`

Comment: Thanks Josh. Also @RezaSoltani I am accounting the 2d as 1d because it is iterated through as if it were flat. Also, the length of a<=n and its loop is simultaneous with the for's.